# How can I find the implementation/source code of an interface in .NET?

Tags: decompilation, dll, .net

So I'm disassembling the Winnov.Amalga.Core.Session.Common.dll, and trying to figure out how the WriteScriptCommand works.

I'm absolutely new to .NET, so go easy on me, please.
You can find the dll yourself here: [Link](ftp://winnov.com/public/Costa/Amalga/Amalga_Developer_Kit_V1.zip) under the Binary folder.

Below is pretty much the only reference I found. EDIT: From searching through the decompiled dll.

```
using System;
namespace winnov.Amalga.core
{
  public interface ISession
  {
     string Configuration { get; set; }
     SessionState { get; }
     TimeSpan Duration { get; }
     string ArchiveBasePath { get; set; }
     string ArchivePath { get; }
     void Start();
     void Stop();
     void ApplyPreset(string presetxml);
     void writeScriptCommand(string name, string value);
   }
}
```

Comment: @JasonGeffner I've already gotten it decompiled in DotPeek. That's how I found the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the decompiled code for the `Winnov.Amalga.Core.Client` constructor, you'll see that `this._Session` is a web service interface to whatever web service was used when constructing `Winnov.Amalga.Core.Client`. Thus, `Session.WriteScriptCommand()` is a server-side function and its code is not in `Winnov.Amalga.Core.Session.Common.dll`.

Comment: Thank you! But in the interest of learning, what part tipped you off to that conclusion?

Comment: Decompiling with ILSpy and seeing that `WriteScriptCommand()` is just a stub in the `ISession` interface, then looking at the `Client` constructor to see how `_Session` is initialized. And finally, disassembling with IDA Pro to make sure I didn't miss anything that might have been caused by a bug in ILSpy.